# I am getting error as unrecognized rule in this lex program

Tags: linux, flex-lexer, lex, compiler-construction

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int vowel=0;
%}

%%

[aeiouAEIOU]
{
vowel++;
}

%%

int main()
{
  char str[200];    
  gets(str);
  yylex();
  printf("Vowels:",vowel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the way you wrote the program, then the error is correct. In Flex, the action for a rule must start on the same line as the pattern.

From the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html#Rules-Section):

> 5.2 Format of the Rules Section
>
> The rules section of the flex input contains a series of rules of the form:
>
> ```
>  pattern   action
> ```
>
> where the pattern must be unindented and the action must begin on the same line.

As written, you have supplied `{` as a pattern. That's not a valid pattern, and so flex complains.

Comment: Thank you rici for your answer. I fixed it.